# Enabling jmx authentication on java app run as a service using procrun

Tags: java, jmx, procrun

I am running a java app as a service using procrun. The app is running fine when the JMX authentication is not enabled, but when I add an access and password files, restrict permissions on the password file and enable the JMX authentication, the app is not starting and giving `1074: The process terminated unexpectedly` error.

Below is the script I am using to register the app as a service using the latest version of procrun.

```
cd E:\MyApp
MyApp.exe //IS//MyApp --Install=%cd%\MyApp.exe --Jvm="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll" --JvmMx=2048 --JvmMs=2048 --Startup=auto --StartMode jvm --StartClass com.MyApp --StartParams start --StartMethod start --StopMode jvm --StopClass com.MyApp --StopParams stop --StopMethod stop --Classpath=%cd%\MyApp.jar --LibraryPath=%cd%\bin --JvmOptions="-Duser.dir=%cd%" ++JvmOptions=-XX:+RelaxAccessControlCheck ++JvmOptions=-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote ++JvmOptions=-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1099 ++JvmOptions=-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false ++JvmOptions=-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=true ++JvmOptions=-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.access.file=E:\MyApp\Conf\jmxremote.access ++JvmOptions=-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.password.file=E:\MyApp\Conf\jmxremote.password --JvmOptions=-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC --JvmOptions=-XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=40 ++JvmOptions=-Dorg.xml.sax.parser="com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.SAXParser"  ++JvmOptions=-Djavax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory="com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl"  ++JvmOptions=-Djavax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory="com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl" --LogPath=E:\Logs --LogLevel=DEBUG --StdOutput=auto --StdError=auto --StartPath=%cd% --StopPath=%cd% --DisplayName=MyApp
```

Any clues on what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a problem with your password file. At first just use a simple jmx configuration like mine. Here is my simple JMX configuration for startup:

```
 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote 
 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=11099 
 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false        
 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false 
 -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=localhost
 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=11098
```

Comment: I also have changed jmx port to a not reserved one. Please use it and inform me.